# What's the difference between 候 and 等?

Tags: mandarin, word

I've usually seen in my little Mandarin learning experience, that when people express `wait`, they usually use `等`. However, I just noticed the following phrase in Sina Weibo:

```
请稍候...
```

I know `请` means `please`, and I looked up in my dictionary, that `稍` is `a little` and `候` is `wait`. So the sentence seems to express `please wait a little...`, which is fine in the context (I tried reloading the data, for your information).

So what's the difference between `等` and `候`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None. They are synonyms, although they also have separate different meanings.

稍等 = 稍候 = wait a minute.

等候 = 等 = 候, although 候 is rarely used as a single character with this meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There is no differences between 等 and 候. Both means "to wait". You can also put them together as a word 等候, with the same meaning - to wait.

However, 候 sounds like the usage in classical Chinese (archaic Chinese), and therefore rarely use as only one single character in modern Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of stating "please wait", 等 and 候 both mean the "to wait".

However they each have other meanings in different context. For example, 等 also means "level" (as in 等級, 等地). 候 also means "to serve" (as in 伺候).

Answer (score 0):

We say“我等你”. It means"I wait for you".
But we don't say“我候你”